# How to put 3 variables in a heap

Tags: visual-c++, heap

My teacher taught us to make a Max Heap with array. Now in a assignment we have to put three variables in each nodes of heap and I dont know how to do that because array can only hold one data so I need help because I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Have you learned about `struct` yet?  structs contain mulitple fields (variables) and you can create arrays of structs...

Comment: That thought did not came into the mind. Thanks

Comment: I am having trouble creating max heap with objects like I cannot grasp the concept of it can you give me an idea?

Comment: Usually you'll have one of the fields be they 'key' that you use to order the heap, so when comparing elements for max/min/less/greater, you'll just compare this numeric field and ignore the others.  Other than that, the heap continues to work in exactly the same way.  If you have a more specific question, show what you've tried and what you are (specifically) having trouble with.  Always try to structure your question as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what your problem is.